# Android Digits returns nothing

Tags: java, android, twitter-oauth, twitter-digits

Why Android Digits do not always return onSuccess or onFalure after number verification? It just finish DigitsActivity and do nothing, but sometimes its okay and I receive onSuccess.

```
public void initForm(){
    Digits.getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679089/fabric-digits-returns-a-null-object-of-phonenumber-after-otp-verification-on-and
    DigitsAuthConfig.Builder digitsAuthConfigBuilder = new DigitsAuthConfig.Builder()
            .withAuthCallBack(new AuthCallback() {
                @Override
                public void success(DigitsSession digitsSession, String s) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    TwitterAuthToken token = (TwitterAuthToken)digitsSession.getAuthToken();
                    DigitsOAuthSigning oauthSigning = new DigitsOAuthSigning(SapronApplication.conf(), token);
                    Map<String, String> authHeaders = oauthSigning.getOAuthEchoHeadersForVerifyCredentials();
                    requestToken(authHeaders.get("X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization"));

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(DigitsException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .withPhoneNumber("+7");


    Digits.authenticate(digitsAuthConfigBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same problem and also phoneNumber returned as null like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679089/fabric-digits-returns-a-null-object-of-phonenumber-after-otp-verification-on-and). I resolved the problem while using custom button. The main problem was not clearing the digits session properly and setting new AuthCallback in withAuthCallBack() in every click. The code that resolved my problem is given below. Hope it will help someone who need to use custom button for digits.....

```
findViewById(R.id.customDigitsButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            verifyMobileUsingDigits();
        }
    });

private AuthCallback authCallback;
public void verifyMobileUsingDigits(){
    logoutFabricDigits("verifyMobileUsingDigits");// manual deletion of all digit sessions, as only Digits.getSessionManager().clearActiveSession() did not helped me.....
    if(authCallback == null){
        authCallback = new AuthCallback() {
            @Override
            public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication successful for " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(DigitsException exception) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
    }
    DigitsAuthConfig.Builder digitsAuthConfigBuilder = new DigitsAuthConfig.Builder()
            .withAuthCallBack(authCallback)
            .withPhoneNumber("+880")
            .withEmailCollection(false)
            .withThemeResId(R.style.CustomDigitsTheme);
    Digits.authenticate(digitsAuthConfigBuilder.build());
}

public static void logoutFabricDigits(String TAG){
    try {
        Map<Long, DigitsSession> digitsSessionMap = Digits.getSessionManager().getSessionMap();
        if(digitsSessionMap != null){
            Set<Long> digitIdSet = new HashSet<>(digitsSessionMap.keySet());
            for(Long digitId : digitIdSet){
                DigitsSession digitsSession = digitsSessionMap.get(digitId);
                if(digitsSession != null){
                    Digits.getSessionManager().clearSession(digitsSession.getId());
                }
            }
        }
        Digits.getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i don't know what's wrong with custom button and custom authcallback. Solved problem by using DigitsAuthButton.

```
  digitsButton = (DigitsAuthButton) findViewById(R.id.auth_button);
   // digitsButton.setAuthTheme(R.style.AppTheme2);
    digitsButton.setCallback(new AuthCallback() {
        @Override
        public void success(DigitsSession digitsSession, String s) {
            new MaterialDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this)
                    .progress(true, 0)
                    .show();
           TwitterAuthToken token = (TwitterAuthToken)digitsSession.getAuthToken();
            DigitsOAuthSigning oauthSigning = new DigitsOAuthSigning(SapronApplication.conf(), token);
            Map<String, String> authHeaders = oauthSigning.getOAuthEchoHeadersForVerifyCredentials();
            requestToken(authHeaders.get("X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization"));
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(DigitsException e) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

as @rallat commented here https://github.com/twitter/digits-android/issues/6

they changed their authcallback into a weak reference, to avoid memory leaks.

just create the callback variable in your context, f.e:

```
AuthCallback authCallback = new AuthCallback() {
    @Override
    public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
        // Do something with the session
        Log.d(TAG, "success: " + phoneNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(DigitsException exception) {
        // Do something on failure
        Log.d(TAG, "failure: ");
        //show error or somthing
    }
};
```

and pass it to your builder:

```
digitsButton.setCallback(authCallback);
```